# Can I use a function as the name of a function?

Tags: php

I am modifying my PHP framework and trying to figure out an easier way to deal with different request types.

Currently I have this block in a controller method

```
$methodHandler = self::getMethodHandler(__FUNCTION__);
$this->$methodHandler();
```

Where getMethodHandler is

```
protected static function getMethodHandler($function) {
    return $function."_".ucwords(strtolower(Request::getMethod()));
}
```

Ideally I want to reduce that two lines into one but PHP ain't having it

```
$this->self::getMethodHandler(__FUNCTION__)();
```

Anyway I could do this?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$this->{self::getMethodHandler(__FUNCTION__)}();
```

That will evaluate `self::getMethodHandler(__FUNCTION__)` and call the result as a method of `$this`.

Comment: Perfect thanks! I tried wrapping (), didn't think of {}. Is there any name to wrapping in {}, I'd like to look into it.

Comment: @MattVotsikas It's called interpolation.  It's usually used in strings like `"the value of var is $var"` or `"\$this->var is {$this->var}"`, but the same concept applies outside of strings when something is wrapped in curly braces.  Another example would be calling a function with a number in it like `{"function_$i"}()`.  That would call `function_2` if $i was 2.